# Meaning of PCA on transposed data matrix

Tags: pca, interpretation, graph-theory

Conceptually, what would be the meaning of performing PCA on the $M'$ of initial matrix $M=[n \times m]$ where $n$ rows refer to observations and $m$ columns refer to variables?

### The problem

Perform PCA  for $N=10$ observations of a network/graph $G_n=[p \times p]$. PCA has been performed on $M'$ where  $M= [N \times p^2]$, where each $G_n$ has been put into $M$ by vectorisation.

```
[U S V] = svd(cov(M'))
PC = U'*M
```

By convention the columns indicate different variables, and the rows the different observations but I performed PCA on the transposed matrix and interesting results came up. Are these by any chance interpretable, or just meaningless?

Comment: Did you center your data matrix $M$? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, by subtracting the mean of each $M_n$, where $M_n = [v_1, v_2, ... , v_p]$ the vectorised $G_n$ by $M_n=G_n(:)$;

Comment: You might want to add this to the question because the issue of centering is  crucial here. You are centering rows (whereas usually in PCA you would be centering columns).

Comment: You may want to check https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7144/77888. Also, Google "PCA transpose trick".