# PCA: Treating samples rather than variables as the dimensions to be reduced (will something similar to the transpose trick work?)

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a matrix of data with approximately 200,000 samples and 30 variables. The variables have been standardized because their original units of measurement are arbitrary/irrelevant.

I am interested in eventually clustering the *variables*, not the *samples*, but want to do PCA first so I don't have 200,000 dimensions when clustering.

I have come across the PCA [transpose trick](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/how-to-perform-pca-for-data-of-very-high-dimensionality/7144#7144), and I understand that it's for situations when it would result in a smaller correlation matrix (and that in my case it would make the correlation matrix larger). I also understand that the transpose trick is **not** "just transpose the data and do PCA on that" because you would end up [centering the samples, not the variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392425/146747). (And intuitively "centering the samples" doesn't make sense - it would be like trying to center a person by subtracting the mean of their height, weight, age, and income.)

But if I take the general idea of the transpose trick and do PCA using [the solution described in the second link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392425/146747) to avoid incorrect centering, would give me the result I am trying to get - the  ability to calculate PC scores for variables?

If I am reading that solution correctly, then if $A_c$ is the data matrix with p=30 variables as columns, n=200,000 samples as rows, and the *variables* centered or standardized, I would do PCA of $\dfrac{1}{n}{A_c}{A_c}^T$, giving me an enormous eigenvector matrix (but I think all but 30 would have 0 as the eigenvalue).

**Main question:** Could I then use the selected eigenvectors from that enormous matrix and use them to calculate PC scores for the variables? Calling that eigenvector matrix $V_b$ (b for big), the PC scores for variables would be ${A_c}^{T}{V_b}$? Are scores calculated in this way appropriate for use in later analyses such as trying to cluster the variables?

**Secondary question:** I don't actually need to make that enormous matrix, right? Using the transpose trick, if I do PCA the usual way with a 30x30 correlation matrix for variables ($\dfrac{1}{n}{A_c}^T{A_c}$), then if $V_s$ (s for small) is the eigenvector matrix from doing that I can use ${A_c}V_s$ to get the first 30 eigenvectors I would have gotten in $V_b$. And then the PC scores for my variables would be ${A_c}^T{A_c}{V_s}$?

I think this is different from a biplot - a biplot would give variables scores/coordinates on axes that come from treating the *variables* as dimensions to be reduced, and this (hopefully) gives the variables scores/coordinates on axes that come from treating the *samples* as dimensions to be reduced.

**Edit:** I think there is a flaw in my reasoning - my PCs would not be "axes that come from treating the samples as the dimensions to be reduced" if the samples aren't centered. There would be [something like an intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22331/146747) in there to mess things up. Is there a way to fix or work around that, or is this whole approach flawed?

**To be clear, my question is now:** Is there a better way to accomplish what I was trying to do here? Treat samples as the dimensions to be reduced to make it easier to cluster the variables?